# CSS select first div of every line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How would I go about selecting the first element of every line?

Here's what I'm trying to do:
[image: margins]
The yellow circles are where the two elements are connected. I need to add spacing between these hopefully using some kind of CSS selector. I can use anyother language if needed.

The website is responsive and therefore I cannot just add "&nbsp(semicolon)"
 in the middle or that will make the divs go right every single line. This works the same with :not(:first-child) margin-left as all the elements of each line move to the right.

So, in summary:

- I need to add spacing inbetween the divs, I have marked where the spacing needs to be
- I cannot use margin-left as it will space the divs on the next lines to the right

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: nth-chid(x) maybe unless you tried it already :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably know on which screen-widths the boxes jump to the next line, so just use those break-points as a cue for your `:nth-child()` selectors.

For example: on screens >800px wide, it will show 4 blocks on each line? Add your desired styling to `.classname:nth-child(4n+1)` (every 4th, starting with the 1st) within a `@media screen and (min-width 800px) {}`.

So it would look like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width 800px) {
  .classname:nth-child(4n+1) {
    margin-right: 2px;
  }
}
```

Of course you will have to play with the `:nth-child()` selector and break-points to exactly achieve what you want, but since you have not shared even a small bit of code, I have no idea how it should look like.